# How can I dispose of cement pavers in Delaware County, Pennsylvania?

Tags: pavers

I have roughly 110 (8 by 16) cement pavers that I need to dispose of in Delaware County, PA. How can they be disposed of?

Comment: I also live in Delaware County PA.  I would love to have them

Comment: As others have said, definitely give them away! Find @Mark S, (the chat room can help), and give them to him! Donating to a charity, like Ecnerwal suggested, is awesome! Many will come get them. We have a church email chain where we offer things to each other. Lots of people are doing projects, or know people who are, and can't afford things like these. You're a kind person. Don't underestimate the power of your gift. "One man's trash is another man's treasure!"

Comment: I'd take em, neighbor.. :p

Answer (score 13):

- A: Craigslist, curb alert, free pavers.
- B: By the side of the road, with a sign "free pavers".
- To really make them move,  C: by the side of the road, a sign,
  "pavers, $2 each" (don't expect the $2, but you could get lucky, and
  the folks that think they are stealing them might be more eager than
  the ones that are taking them for free.)
- Contact your local community garden or [Habitat for Humanity](http://www.habitat.org/) and donate them.

Comment: *Love* option three!

Answer (score 6):

Sell them on Craig's list or Ebay!!  Those things are valuable.  Do you have any neighbors with drainage issues, land slides in their back yards?  Find a RESTORE type outfit nearby.  They'll come and do all the work (as they should)and take them away.  Put an ad up in your neighborhood hardware/lumber yard.  Don't forget to go TALK to the manager(s) of the store, they'll know someone who would love to get paver CMU's cheaply.

I am sure that there is a concrete/asphalt recycling place nearby.  You just have to load, haul, unload all of this GOLD with no help.

Another option is to use them as a garden wall, similar to ledger stone.  15 to 18 inches high, slightly battered, drainage and soil behind, a thick concrete cap and you've increased the value of your home more than a remodeled kitchen or an extra bathroom.  This enables a new dimension to your yard versus 2 dimensional flat.

Look up debris hauling, recycling, concrete removal...if you want to get rid of those pavers you shouldn't have to lift a finger other than making a few calls.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a local "freecycle" e-mail group? Always works for me, where I live. Just join (free), post your offer, sit back and wait for e-mails from people who want them.